# Eclipse Profiler Tool URL

Tags: eclipse-plugin, profiler

Where can I get the url for the eclipse profilert plugin ?
I want to update it directly to my eclipse rather than downloading and installing

I need it for Eclipse 3.2 and Eclipse Galileo

Answer (score 0):

Wow, 2004, that's ancient. Check out [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/) instead. Its URL is

```
http://download.eclipse.org/tptp/updates
```